# curl crashes in threaded calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl

I read the SO articles if `curl` is thread-safe. This very simple code crashes - not always but when I call the program several times in a row [not parallel] then it crashes either with a segmentation fault or with the below error.

That far I am convinced I follow the rules regarding `curl` and threads as stated in the documentation.

In tests I could find out that it crashes in `curl_easy_perform()`.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

class curlClass
{
private:
    CURL * curl {};
    CURLcode res;
    const char * sUrl;

public:
    auto loadDataFromUrl()     -> void;
    static auto initCurl()     -> void;
    static auto releaseCurl()  -> void;
    static auto callbackSaveData( void * content, size_t size, size_t nmemb, curlClass * classInstance ) -> size_t;
    curlClass( const char * );
    ~curlClass();
};

auto curlClass::initCurl() -> void
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_SSL);
}

auto curlClass::releaseCurl() -> void
{
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

curlClass::curlClass( const char * sUrl ) : sUrl( sUrl )
{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
}

curlClass::~curlClass()
{
    curl_easy_cleanup( curl );
}

auto curlClass::callbackSaveData( __attribute__ ((unused))  void *contents, 
    size_t size, 
    size_t nmemb, 
    __attribute__ ((unused))    curlClass * classInstance
) -> size_t
{
    return size * nmemb;
}

auto curlClass::loadDataFromUrl() -> void
{
    if ( curl )
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, (CURLoption) CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, nullptr);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, (CURLoption) CURLOPT_URL, sUrl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, (CURLoption) CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackSaveData);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        printf( "Return: %d\n", res );
    }
}

auto worker( const char * sUrl ) -> void
{
    curlClass myInstance( sUrl );
    myInstance.loadDataFromUrl();
}

int main(void)
{
    curl_version_info_data * curl_version = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);

    printf( "Curl version=%s\n", curl_version->version );
    curlClass::initCurl();

    std::thread thread1( worker, "https://www.google.com");
    std::thread thread2( worker, "https://www.google.com" );
    std::thread thread3( worker, "https://www.google.com" );
    std::thread thread4( worker, "https://www.google.com" );
    std::thread thread5( worker, "https://www.google.com" );
    std::thread thread6( worker, "https://www.google.com" );
    std::thread thread7( worker, "https://www.google.com" );

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();
    thread5.join();
    thread6.join();
    thread7.join();

    curlClass::releaseCurl();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I compiled the new `curl` version `7.46.0`. This is one of the possible error dumps:

```
Curl version=7.46.0
*** glibc detected *** ./curl_crash: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fcd200056d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x76618)[0x7fcd2ff4a618]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7fcd2ff4f65c]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(CRYPTO_free+0x19)[0x7fcd2f9f13f9]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(+0xf407d)[0x7fcd2f9d307d]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(ERR_clear_error+0xd)[0x7fcd2f9efd1d]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(+0x4849c)[0x7fcd30a2d49c]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(+0x4b970)[0x7fcd30a30970]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(+0x1073d)[0x7fcd309f573d]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(+0x20451)[0x7fcd30a05451]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(+0x31e0e)[0x7fcd30a16e0e]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(curl_multi_perform+0xdd)[0x7fcd30a1780d]
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4(curl_easy_perform+0x10b)[0x7fcd30a1001b]
./curl_crash(_ZN9curlClass15loadDataFromUrlEv+0x88)[0x408002]
./curl_crash(_Z6workerPKc+0x2c)[0x408051]
./curl_crash(_ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvPKcES1_EE9_M_invokeIILm0EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIIXspT_EEE+0x40)[0x409818]
./curl_crash(_ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvPKcES1_EEclEv+0x1d)[0x409711]
./curl_crash(_ZNSt6thread5_ImplISt12_Bind_simpleIFPFvPKcES3_EEE6_M_runEv+0x1c)[0x40968e]
/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb5c10)[0x7fcd30790c10]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x77f6)[0x7fcd2e81c7f6]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fcd2ffaf09d]
======= Memory map: ========
```

I do not have really a clue what is going wrong. When I start the program 5 times then at least once it crashes.

What am I doing wrong or is it possible - according to the dump - that I am using an old SSL library?

Command line to compile:

`g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wextra curl_crash.cpp -o curl_crash -lcurl -rdynamic && ./curl_crash`

Comment: Your code violates almost every possible rule of memory management. It is expected to crash.

Comment: @SergeyA it would be nice to tell which. Thank you! The funny thing is there is no any memory management at all... It is a very simple test case.

Comment: @AlBundy see the [TLS section of the Thread-safe FAQ for curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html). It seems to indicate that you're missing some locking for openssl; which is needed to get curl to work properly in a multi-threaded manner.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this post. I still cannot believe it. I've being trying to find a bug the whole day and I realized I have openssl 1.0.2 and am having this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stopped too early reading the SSL library documentation. Thanks to `Petesh`, who pointed out the issue while accessing `openssl`, I could then fix fast the problem.

As stated in the `curl` documentation [Thread-safe](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html) --> `TLS` --> `OpenSSL` I had to use the functions. I adapted it to C++11 standard:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <vector>

class SslCurlWrapper
{
private:
    static std::vector<std::mutex> vectorOfSslMutex;
    static auto id_function() -> unsigned long { return ( pthread_self() ); }
    static auto locking_function(int, int, const char *, int) -> void;

public:
    SslCurlWrapper();
    ~SslCurlWrapper();
};

std::vector<std::mutex> SslCurlWrapper::vectorOfSslMutex( CRYPTO_num_locks() );

//----------------------------------------
auto SslCurlWrapper::locking_function( int mode,
                                       int n,
                                       __attribute__ ((unused)) const char * file,
                                       __attribute__ ((unused)) int line
                                     ) -> void
//----------------------------------------
{
    if ( mode & CRYPTO_LOCK )   vectorOfSslMutex [n].lock();
    else                        vectorOfSslMutex [n].unlock();
}

//------------------------------
SslCurlWrapper::SslCurlWrapper()
//------------------------------
{
    CRYPTO_set_id_callback( id_function );
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback( locking_function );
}

//-------------------------------
SslCurlWrapper::~SslCurlWrapper()
//-------------------------------
{
    CRYPTO_set_id_callback( nullptr );
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback( nullptr );
}
```

It can be then used like this:

```
int main(void)
{
        SslCurlWrapper sslObject;    // hook is set up
        // here it is safe to use the curl library in a multi-thread-environment
}       // hook is released/uninstalled
```

Compile command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -c SslCurlWrapper.cpp
```

The `-lcrypto` library has to be added to the compiler command line in order the linker does not complain.

My personal remark is that I am a bit surprised that the default mode in the `openssl` library does not implement the both mentioned function that way to avoid each programmer has to start from scratch. This could be the minimum-implementation...

The test shell script called the program 200 times without any crash. Before it crashed immediately. For me it is fixed.

I do not understand the very useless comment from SergeyA.

Comment: Just to add a bit of information: I am currently struggling with this same problem. Tried the code suggested in the curl site (with the pthreads library) to no avail and then rolled up a piece of code very similar to yours. Seems to be more resilient but eventually fails under stress tests with the very same stack trace. A bitch to fix since you can't possibly catch it on runtime and resume operations... Seems to be a bug in openSSL when there are many simultaneous handshakes taking place at the same time. Hope it works for you :).

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan I am very sorry to read this. I use this solution in my project and there can be up to 100 simultaneously threads. It works like a charm. Which CURL library are using? Do you receive segmentation fault?

Comment: As a matter of fact, just a few minutes ago I got it working. I have been fumbling around with this most of the morning, tracing the problem back to the openssl library and reading the literature about it. Trying it with 1.0.1f seems to solve the problem as we've racked around 30000 requests spread on 40+ threads with no problems on one machine while other randomly crashes and loses data... Definitely something fishy with my develoment machine :). No segfault, just memory corruption. libcurl/7.35.0. Thanks for sharing!.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan :-)))